# Lazy load CoreData relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, lazy-loading

What is the correct approach to lazy loading CoreData relationships?

Say I have a Project object and a ProjectFilter object which may or may not already exist, will this work as expected?

```
- (ProjectFilter *)filter
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"filter"];
    ProjectFilter *filter = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"filter"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"filter"];

    if (!filter) {
        filter = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ProjectFilter" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        self.filter = filter;
    }
    return filter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible idea and you shouldn't do it.

In a very simple core data stack you can have everything running on the main thread.  But as your app gets more complex you will almost always need to have background context.  If you have multiple context writing to core-data at the same time you can get merge conflicts.  You can tell core-data to auto-resolve merged conflicts - but that isn't a great solution because you are guaranteed to lose data that way.   So a common solution is to have a single queue for writing and use the main thread queue only for reading.

In your setup you are hiding the fact that you are writing to core data.  So simply accessing `project.filter` will cause a write in core data.  If you are trying to manage when and where you are writing to core-data this it is very very very hard for a developer to recognize this as a write.

Even if your core-data is not using this setup it is almost always important for a developer to know when he is writing to core-data.  After a write you have to save.  After a write you might need to be aware that it will affect a fetched results controller.  After a write you can get merged conflicts.

Comment: a method `createFilterPropertyIfNeeded` would be preferable.